# Excel hours format (XML) using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, momentjs

In excel when putting in a cell the time of `14:44:30`, in the XML workbook the value appears as `0.614236111111111`

```
<row r="1" customFormat="false" hidden="false" customHeight="false" outlineLevel="0" collapsed="false">
<c r="C1" s="40" t="n">
   <v>0.614236111111111</v>
</c>
</row>
```

How can I convert hours to this excel format using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given number is a fraction of 24 hours.

So the function that would do the job can be

```
var convertToExcelFormat = function(time){
 var seconds_in_24h = 86400; //24*60*60
 var a = time.split(':');
 var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); //convert time to seconds
 return (seconds/seconds_in_24h).toFixed(15) // return the fraction in given format
}
```